# How do apps skin things like the keyboard, clock, google search, buttons, etc?

Tags: android, button, themes

I have been looking around the market and have seen apps that skin things like the keyboard, clock, google search, buttons,etc

How do they do that...changing system files?

Take for instance the case of SPB SHELL 3D ...an app that changes the user interface. What approach so they take?

Thank you for your help and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they work by listening for the homescreen intent. When you click home, you're technically just going into another app, one that has been written to appear when you click home. When you install multiple apps that listen for a common intent (eg. opening a photo, sending an email, providing the home screen) a dialog appears asking you which one you'd like to use with the option of setting a default. On a new phone there is only one home app, so no dialog appears and it goes straight into the default home app. Try installing [LauncherPro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcher) and then click home to see what happens. For more info on Intents, head over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: just wanted to add: most things in Android can be changed without modifying system files. You can just add tons of custom keyboards, lauchers and so on and then choose your favourite. Themes that modify the look of buttons and such stuff in ALL apps need to write in system folders, so no way without rooting your device.